# ASP not Rendering Produced page

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering

have an ASP Page that is not getting any errors, however after the page loads the page is rendered as a blank page. However if I copy the produced code, and place that into another ASP page and load that page it renderes just fine. It is almost like I need something at the end of the code to say now that you are done running the code show the html that was produced.

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" Language="c#" CodeBehind="DefaultCS.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefaultCS.WebForm1"%>



string[] projects = null;
//string winlogon = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
//string User = winlogon.Substring(8, winlogon.Length - 8);
projects = renderProjectIDs("HCQ763");
string Level1 = "";
string Level2 = "";
string Level3 = "";
int linedone = 0;



Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html>" + System.Environment.NewLine);

Response.Write("<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);

Response.Write("<head runat=\"server\"> </head>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("    <body>" + System.Environment.NewLine);

    Response.Write("<form id=\"form1\" runat=\"server\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write("<asp:TreeView runat=\"server\" Width=\"105px\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write("<Nodes>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Text=\"Capital Projects\" Value=\"Capital Projects\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);

string[] tempArray = new string[2];
for(int y=0; y<projects.Length; y++)
  {
    tempArray = projects[y].Split('|');
    linedone = 0;
    if ((Level3 != "") && (Level3 != tempArray[5])) //If a level 3 has been built and we come back up we need to make an end TreeNode
    {
        Response.Write("</asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine); //End the Last Level 3 Node
    }
    if ((Level2 != "") && (Level2 != tempArray[3]))  //If a level 2 has been built and we come back up we need to make an end TreeNode
    {
        Response.Write("</asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine); //End the last Level 2 Node
        Level3 = "";
    }
    if ((Level1 != "") && (Level1 != tempArray[1])) //If a level 1 has been built and we come back up we need to make an end TreeNode
    {
        Response.Write("</asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine); //End the last Level 1 Node
        Level2 = "";
    }





    if ((Level1 != tempArray[1]) && (tempArray[1] != tempArray[3])) //Level 1 Node has changes
    {
       Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Text=\"" + tempArray[0] + "\" Value=\"" + tempArray[0] + "\">" + System.Environment.NewLine); //Write the new Level 1 Node
       Level1 = tempArray[1];
    }
    else if (tempArray[1] == tempArray[3]) // Level 2 and Level 3 ID in the database are the same this means that the Record is a CIP
    {
        //Write out the CIP
        linedone = 1;
        Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Value=\"" + tempArray[8] + "\" Text=\"" + tempArray[1] + "\" NavigateUrl=\"CapitalText.aspx?CID=" + tempArray[8] + "\" Target=\"frame_main\"></asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }  
    if ((Level2 != tempArray[3]) && (tempArray[3] != tempArray[5])) //Level 2 Node Changed
    {
        Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Text=\"" + tempArray[2] + "\" Value=\"" + tempArray[2] + "\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);   //Write the new Level 2 Node
        Level2 = tempArray[3];
    } else if ((tempArray[3] == tempArray[5]) && (linedone == 0)) // Level 2 and Level 3 ID in the database are the same this means that the Record is a CIP
        {
            //Write out the CIP
            linedone = 1;
            Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Value=\"" + tempArray[8] + "\" Text=\"" + tempArray[2] + "\" NavigateUrl=\"CapitalText.aspx?CID=" + tempArray[8] + "\" Target=\"frame_main\"></asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    if ((Level3 != tempArray[5]) && (tempArray[5] != tempArray[7]))
    {
        Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Text=\"" + tempArray[4] + "\" Value=\"" + tempArray[4] + "\">" + System.Environment.NewLine); //Write the new Level 3 Node
        Level3 = tempArray[5];
    }
    else if ((tempArray[5] == tempArray[7]) && (linedone == 0)) // IF Level 3 and Level 4 IDs in the database are the same this means that the Record is a CIP
    {
           //Write out the CIP
        linedone = 1;
        Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Value=\"" + tempArray[8] + "\" Text=\"" + tempArray[4] + "\" NavigateUrl=\"CapitalText.aspx?CID=" + tempArray[8] + "\" Target=\"frame_main\"></asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
    if ((tempArray[5] != tempArray[7]) && (linedone == 0))
    {
        Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Value=\"" + tempArray[8] + "\" Text=\"" + tempArray[6] + "\" NavigateUrl=\"CapitalText.aspx?CID=" + tempArray[8] + "\" Target=\"frame_main\"></asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }




 }


          Response.Write("</asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Response.Write("</asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write("</Nodes>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("</asp:TreeView>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
  Response.Write("</form>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Response.Write("</body>" + System.Environment.NewLine);

Response.Write("</html>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
%>
```

This is the Code that is produced

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server"> </head>
        <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TreeView runat="server" Width="105px">
    <Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Capital Projects" Value="Capital Projects">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Hennepin County Total" Value="Hennepin County Total">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Public Works" Value="Public Works">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Transportation Roads & Bridges" Value="Transportation Roads & Bridges">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2986401" Text="2986401  CSAH 3 - Construct Lake St ramps at I-35W - Participation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2986401" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2070500" Text="2070500  CSAH 5 - Reconst. Franklin Ave Bridge over Mississippi River" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2070500" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2142600" Text="2142600 CSAH 20 - Reconstruct Blake Road from TH 7 to Excelsior Blvd" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2142600" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2141200" Text="2141200  CSAH 28 - Participate in MnDOT I-494 Ramp reconstruction" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2141200" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2141100" Text="2141100 CSAH 30 - Reconst 93rd Ave N fr Xylon Ave to East of Winnetka" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2141100" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="2974800" Text="2974800  CSAH 34 - Reconst Normandale fr W 94th St to Mt Normandale Dr" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=2974800" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Housing Community Works and Transit" Value="Housing Community Works and Transit">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002195" Text="1002195   Economic Development Infrastructure Fund" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002195" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001560" Text="1001560   Penn Avenue Community Works" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001560" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031720" Text="0031720   Community Works Corridor Planning" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031720" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001648" Text="1001648   Lowry Avenue NE Community Works" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001648" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031721" Text="0031721   Fort Snelling Upper Post" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031721" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002318" Text="1002318   Bottineau LRT Community Works" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002318" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031591" Text="0031591   Community Works Northwest Corridor" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031591" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031805" Text="0031805   Southwest LRT Community Works" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031805" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031742" Text="0031742   Minnehaha-Hiawatha Community Works" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031742" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Environmental  Services" Value="Environmental  Services">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031704" Text="0031704   HERC Facility Preservation & Improvement" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031704" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002150" Text="1002150   HERC Pres & Improvements 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002150" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031814" Text="0031814   HERC District Energy" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031814" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000319" Text="1000319   Transfer Station Facility Pres 2012-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000319" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002151" Text="1002151   Transfer Station Pres 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002151" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Property Services" Value="Property Services">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031822" Text="0031822   Environmental Health & Safety 2011-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031822" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002153" Text="1002153   Environmental Health & Safety 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002153" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000874" Text="1000874   Government Center Rehabilitation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000874" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031823" Text="0031823   Facility Preservation 2011-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031823" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002154" Text="1002154    Facility Preservation 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002154" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031730" Text="0031730   Multi-building Critical Power" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031730" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031825" Text="0031825   Southdale Regional Ctr Preservation & Remodeling" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031825" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002308" Text="1002308   Ridgedale Regional Center Preservation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002308" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031824" Text="0031824   Building Auto. Sys Upgrades 2011-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031824" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002155" Text="1002155    Building Auto. Sys Upgrades 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002155" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001928" Text="1001928   HCGC Admin Space Efficiency & Security Improvements" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001928" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002242" Text="1002242   Countywide Security Equipment Replacement" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002242" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031827" Text="0031827   Public and Programmatic Furniture Replacement" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031827" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031672" Text="0031672   Accessibility Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031672" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002156" Text="1002156   Accessibility Modifications 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002156" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002158" Text="1002158   Carpet Replacement Program 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002158" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000328" Text="1000328   701 Building Facility Preservation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000328" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002159" Text="1002159   701 Building Facility Preservation 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002159" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000329" Text="1000329   701 Building Office Space Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000329" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002157" Text="1002157    General Office Space & Furniture Mods 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002157" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Public Safety and Judiciary" Value="Public Safety and Judiciary">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Emergency Management" Value="Emergency Management">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001563" Text="1001563   Emergency Mgmt Vehicle Storage Bldg" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001563" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="District Court" Value="District Court">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031746" Text="0031746   Government Center C-11 Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031746" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001655" Text="1001655   Traffic Violations Bureau Improvements" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001655" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000932" Text="1000932   Jury Assembly Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000932" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001168" Text="1001168   Conciliation Court Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001168" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031841" Text="0031841   Hearings & Fines Office Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031841" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031838" Text="0031838   Self Help Center Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031838" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031840" Text="0031840   Brookdale Third Courtroom Completion" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031840" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000931" Text="1000931   Courtroom Communications Syst Refurb 2013-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000931" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002161" Text="1002161   Courtroom Communications Syst Refurb 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002161" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001562" Text="1001562   FJC Courtroom Remodel" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001562" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Community Corrections" Value="Community Corrections">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031789" Text="0031789   Community Corrections Security Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031789" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000320" Text="1000320   Community Corrections Facility Pres 2012-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000320" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002162" Text="1002162   Community Corrections Facility Pres 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002162" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000321" Text="1000321   Community Corrections Flooring Replacement" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000321" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031774" Text="0031774   Probation Furniture & Space Efficiency Impr." NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031774" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031842" Text="0031842   CHS Facility Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031842" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002292" Text="1002292   DOCCR Office Safety Audit Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002292" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031843" Text="0031843   ACF Women's Section Expansion" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031843" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002307" Text="1002307   Hennepin-Ramsey Joint Juvenile Corrections Facility" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002307" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Sheriff" Value="Sheriff">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031762" Text="0031762   Sheriffs Holding Area Security Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031762" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001654" Text="1001654   Sheriff's Enforcement Services Div HQ Facility Mods" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001654" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031775" Text="0031775   Sheriff's Crime Lab Expansion/Remodeling" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031775" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Health" Value="Health">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="North Point Health & Wellness Center" Value="North Point Health & Wellness Center">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031735" Text="0031735   North Minneapolis Community Wellness Center" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031735" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Medical Examiner" Value="Medical Examiner">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002306" Text="1002306   New Regional Medical Examiner's Facility" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002306" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Medical Center" Value="Medical Center">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000323" Text="1000323   HCMC Asset Preservation 2012-2015" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000323" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002163" Text="1002163   HCMC Asset Preservation 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002163" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002512" Text="1002512   HCMC Ambulatory Outpatient Specialty Center" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002512" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031753" Text="0031753   HCMC Simulation Center (and $ placeholder for AOSC)" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031753" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002513" Text="1002513   HCMC Loading Dock Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002513" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001170" Text="1001170   HCMC In-Patient Bed Consolidation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001170" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002293" Text="1002293   HCMC Surgery Center Expansion & Relocation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002293" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001169" Text="1001169   HCMC Blue Building Psychiatric Renovation" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001169" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Health Administration" Value="Health Administration">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002160" Text="1002160   1800 Chicago Detox Ctr Refurbishment" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002160" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Human Services" Value="Human Services">
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Human Services & Public Health" Value="Human Services & Public Health">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002165" Text="1002165   HSPHD Sobering Ctr Development" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002165" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031821" Text="0031821   HSPHD Satellite Facilities" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031821" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001083" Text="1001083   HSPHD Office Space Reconfiguration" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001083" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001597" Text="1001597   HSPHD South Minneapolis Regional Service Center" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001597" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Information Technology" Value="Information Technology">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000325" Text="1000325   IT Community Connections Initiative" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000325" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1002166" Text="1002166   IT Community Connectivity 2016-2020" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1002166" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000978" Text="1000978   IT Furniture & Space Efficiency Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000978" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000979" Text="1000979   IT Data Center Upgrades" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000979" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Resident & Real Estate Services" Value="Resident & Real Estate Services">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031794" Text="0031794   HCGC A-5 / A-6 Space Remodeling" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031794" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Municipal Building Commission" Value="Municipal Building Commission">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031317" Text="0031317   MBC Life/Safety Improvements" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031317" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031483" Text="0031483   MBC Mechanical Systems Upgrades" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031483" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031715" Text="0031715   MBC Interior Court & Elevator Modifications" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031715" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031847" Text="0031847   MBC Critical Power" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031847" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000935" Text="1000935   MBC Exterior Improvements" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000935" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="0031828" Text="0031828   MBC ADC Plumbing" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=0031828" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Housing & Redevelopment Authority" Value="Housing & Redevelopment Authority">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001950" Text="1001950   Affordable Housing 2014 - 2018" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001950" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001951" Text="1001951   Transit Oriented Development 2014 - 2018" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001951" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1001585" Text="1001585   Strategic Acquisition" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1001585" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Text="Regional Railroad Authority" Value="Regional Railroad Authority">
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000899" Text="1000899   Southwest LRT Preliminary Engineering" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000899" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="1000941" Text="1000941  Bottineau LRT" NavigateUrl="CapitalText.aspx?CID=1000941" Target="frame_main"></asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
    </form>

    <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
    <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
        {"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"5a18a494e8e9467fac49ce9161940b5b"}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:65311/13b018507f1c41668db5e77d50bb8154/browserLink" async="async"></script>
    <!-- End Browser Link -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: a side note , you really should not post your connection credentials as part of the connection string. (top of file)

Comment: you can't put server tags in a `Response.Write`.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it. First time poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Write is good for debugging but bad for actual production.
You never know exactly when you get your desired output. I once managed to get my head rendered at the *end* of the page instead of its top.

Move your HTML code out of your Response.Write parts and use plain HTML instead wherever you need actual HTML.
So, instead of this:

```html
Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html>" + System.Environment.NewLine);

Response.Write("<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

use this:

```html
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And switch to coding only where actually required.

Comment: This worked, once I removed the HTML, HEAD, BODY, and FORM tags from the code section, then consolidated all of the code into one section between those tags and their ending tags, it is now rendering it perfect. Thank you for you assistance on this.

Comment: You're welcome. I've made this mistake myself once and it nearly drove me nuts.
P.S: The HTML / ASP tags are a lot easier to validate/find errors this way too. And it's a lot cleaner to the eye.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't creating server controls in a valid way. `<asp:TreeNode>` controls aren't actual html elements, so even though it gets pushed to the client nothing is going to actually be displayed.

Comment: However if I copy the rendered code into an ASP just as it shows, that works perfect.

Comment: @Jarrod McReynolds, It shows because you're copying it into an ASP page which gets rendered on the server. Your output is not valid HTML and elements such as asp:TreeNode are not known to any browser

Comment: So how do I get it to produce this ASP code on the fly, and then have the ASP render the produced code? I see what you are saying when I copy the produced source into an HTML page and try and view it renders blank?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write lines like:

```
Response.Write("<asp:TreeNode Value=\"" + tempArray[8] + "\" Text=\"" + tempArray[4] + "\" NavigateUrl=\"CapitalText.aspx?CID=" + tempArray[8] + "\" Target=\"frame_main\"></asp:TreeNode>" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Response.Write writes to the response stream and anything that is written to it will be sent down to the client browser as is. Since asp:TreeNode (or any other directive that should be processed on the server) is not valid html you're not getting the expected result.

Any asp:* or runat="server" is processed (on the server) and converted into valid HTML and this HTML is what will be send to the client browser.